# Java Stream Using Previous Element in Foreach Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list of numbers with some `0s` inside. Since `0` means invalid measure in my situation, I need change the `0` valued element  with the first non 0 element that I can find in the previous positions.

For example the list

```
45 55 0 0 46 0 39 0 0 0
```

must become

```
45 55 55 55 46 46 39 39 39 39
```

This is the implementation using the classic `for each`

```
      int lastNonZeroVal = 0;
        for (MntrRoastDVO vo : res) {
            if (vo.getValColor() > 0) {
                lastNonZeroVal = vo.getValColor();
            } else {
                vo.setValColor(lastNonZeroVal);
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to implement this with the Java Streams and Lambda Functions?

Since I know that I must not change the source of the stream in the foreach lambda, actually the list is a list of object and I do not change the element of the list but I just assign new values.

This was my first solution

```
int lastNonZeroVal = 1;
resutl.stream().forEach(vo -> {
        if(vo.getValColor()>0){
            lastNonZeroVal=vo.getValColor();
        }else{
            vo.setValColor(lastNonZeroVal);
        }
});
```

But I also read [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java-streams-1-brian-goetz/index.html)

> It's best if the lambdas passed to stream operations are entirely side
>   effect free. that is, that they don't mutate any heapbased state or
>   perform any I/O during their execution.

This is what is worryng me

> the data is partitioned, there's no guarantee that when a given element  is 
>   processed, all elements preceding that element were already processed.

Can this solution  produce invalid results, maybe when the number of elements in the list are high? ?
Event if I do not use `parallelStream()` ?

Comment: could give incorrect results if the stream contains negative numbers....rest cases it looks fine ...

Comment: Why do you want to use a stateless structure (stream) for a stateful operation ?

Comment: I guess this is exactly my error, stream are not the right solution in this case

Comment: @Panciz please either accept the answer or comment what is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify state of objects inside stream. But you can not modify data source state.

The problem is the same as in classic iterating.

Use `forEachOrdered()` to perform

> an action for each element of this stream, in the encounter order of the stream if the stream has a defined encounter order

If you call

```
result.stream.forEachOrdered(...)
```

all elements will be processed sequentially in order.

For sequential streams `forEach` seems to respect the order.

Comment: I specified better what is worryng me.

Comment: Ok this solved the problem of the execution order but  I think I still may have problem with the visibility of the shared variable " Performing the action for one element happens-before performing the action for subsequent elements, but for any given element, the action may be performed in whatever thread the library chooses."

Answer (score 10):

> It's best if the lambdas passed to stream operations are entirely side
>   effect free. that is, that they don't mutate any heapbased state or
>   perform any I/O during their execution.

Your solution does infact have a *side effect*, it changes your source list to a resource list. To avoid that, you need the map operator and transform your stream to a Collection. Because you can not access the previous element the state must be stored outside in a final field. For reasons of brevity I used Integer instead of your object:

```
List<Integer> sourceList = Arrays.asList(45, 55, 0, 0, 46, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0);

final Integer[] lastNonZero = new Integer[1]; // stream has no state, so we need a final field to store it
List<Integer> resultList = sourceList.stream()
             .peek(integer -> {
                 if (integer != 0) {
                     lastNonZero[0] = integer;
                 }
             })
             .map(integer -> lastNonZero[0])
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sourceList); // still the same
System.out.println(resultList); // prints [45, 55, 55, 55, 46, 46, 39, 39, 39, 39]
```

Using a stream for your problem is not the best solution, unless you need some additional operations like filter, other map operations or sort.

Comment: It looks like there are some typos in this solution:
"item" should be changed to "integer" and change the map to: 

    map(integer -> { integer == 0 ? lastNonZero[0] : integer })

Comment: @mancocapac thx for the integer typo, the rest should be correct

Comment: I suggest using `AtomicReference<Integer>` instead `Integer[]`

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this with just stream functions, although it's not particularly clean in my opinion.
You could create your own collector to default to the last entry in the list if the current entry is zero.  Something like this:

```
void AddOrLast(List<Integer> list, Integer value) {
    Integer toAdd = 0;
    if (value != 0) {
        toAdd = value;
    } else {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            toAdd = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    list.add(toAdd);
}

@Test
public void name() {
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(45, 55, 0, 0, 46, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0);

    Collector<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, List<Integer>> nonZeroRepeatCollector =
            Collector.of(
                    ArrayList::new,
                    this::AddOrLast,
                    (list1, list2) -> { list1.addAll(list2); return list1; },
                    (x) -> x);

    List<Integer> collect = nums.stream().collect(nonZeroRepeatCollector);
    System.out.println(collect);
    // OUT: [45, 55, 55, 55, 46, 46, 39, 39, 39, 39]
}
```

The `AddOrLast` method will add the current value if non-zero, otherwise the last entry from the array we're building.

The `nonZeroRepeatCollector` uses the supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher pattern.

- The supplier initialized the returned object. (Our ArrayList)
- The accumulator updated the returned object with the new value. (list.add)
- The combiner is used in the case where the stream was split and needs to be rejoined, in parallel stream for example. (This won't be called in our case)
- The finished is a final action to complete the collection.  In our case, just return the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't be mutating state within a lambda. That said, you could use a custom list extending `ArrayList` and override the `iterator()` and `spliterator()` methods.

*Note that this is using a* `Pair` *class which I've omitted here for brevity.*

```
public class MemoList extends ArrayList<Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2816896625889263498L;

    private final List<MntrRoastDVO> list;

    private MemoList(List<MntrRoastDVO> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static MemoList of(List<MntrRoastDVO> list) {
        return new MemoList(Objects.requireNonNull(list));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO>> iterator() {
        Iterator<MntrRoastDVO> it = list.iterator();

        return new Iterator<Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO>>() {
            private Integer previous = null;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return it.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO> next() {
                MntrRoastDVO next = it.next();
                Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO> pair = new Pair<>(previous, next);

                if (next.getValColor() > 0) {
                    previous = next.getValColor();
                }

                return pair;
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO>> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliterator(iterator(), list.size(), Spliterator.SIZED);
    }
}
```

I would then use it like this.

```
public void doWork(List<MntrRoastDVO> res)
{
    MemoList.of(res).stream().forEach(this::setData);
}

private void setData(Pair<Integer,MntrRoastDVO> pair)
{
    MntrRoastDVO data = pair.two();

    if (data.getValColor() <= 0)
    {
        data.setValColor(pair.one());
    }
}
```

Note that this is not tested using a parallel stream. In fact, I'm almost certain it wouldn't work in parallel.