# Java stream an array list and compare with previous record

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a simple RecordA class that holds an id and an int value. Multiple "sorted" RecordA elements are stored in a list.

I want to traverse the list and compare the current with the previous element and find the diff of their values.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;  

class RecordA{
    Integer id;
    Integer value;
    
    RecordA(Integer id, Integer value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    Integer getId() { return id;}
    Integer getValue() { return value;}
}

class RecordB {
    Integer id;
    Integer value;
    Integer diff;
    
    RecordB(Integer id, Integer value, Integer diff) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.diff = diff;
    }
    
    Integer getId() { return id;}
    Integer getValue() { return value;}
    Integer getDiff() { return diff;}
}

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        List<RecordA> listA = new ArrayList<>();
        RecordA recordA1 = new RecordA(1,10);
        listA.add(recordA1);
        RecordA recordA2 = new RecordA(2,15);
        listA.add(recordA2);
        RecordA recordA3 = new RecordA(3,25);
        listA.add(recordA3);
        RecordA recordA4 = new RecordA(4,30);
        listA.add(recordA4);
        
        System.out.println(listA.size());
    }
}
```

I want using streams (if possible) to compare the current RecordA.value with the previous RecordA.value map the result into a RecordB with the same id and value, but store the current-previous.

At the end the List of RecordB will contain

- 1, 10, 0 //(10-0)
- 2, 15, 5 //(15-10)
- 3, 25, 10 //25-15
- 4, 30, 5  //30-25

I would like to avoid the class for loop and the previous_val variable. Any ideas how to do this with streams?

Comment: Doing this with streams is much harder than is worth it.  Use the loop.  Streams are not built for this.

Comment: To extend on @LouisWasserman's comment: `Stream` are inherently stateless. There are some operations that somewhat introduce constraints, e.g. [`.sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()). As was explained, it is possible to realize this with streams, but it is just not worthwhile; the code will be much harder to read and understand (and possibly slower). Just use an imperative approach.

Comment: I disagree. This is quite easily done with a `Collector`. @LouisWasserman

Comment: @user207421: It is technically possible to do this with a `Collector`, yes.  However, it is much harder than is worth it.  Using a loop is significantly better.

Comment: I would use a loop. Easier to code and read, and does require your stream to be non-parallel.

Comment: You are not avoiding loops by using streams - you just move the loop into the streams library. It's still going to be there, just not as visible and harder to debug.

Comment: Your example "1, 10, 0 //(10-0)" says you want 0 which is 10-0, but 10-0 is 10.  Which value do you actually want for your first element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use IntStream

```
IntStream.range(0, listA.size())
    .map(index -> 
        new RecordB(listA.get(index).getId(), listA.get(index).getValue(),  listA.get(index).getValue() - (index > 0 ? listA.get(index - 1).getValue() : 0))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I would like to avoid the class for loop and the previous_val variable. Any ideas how to do this with streams?"*

This is a somewhat un-intuitive approach, I had to looked it up actually.
*[StackOverflow – Java Stream Using Previous Element in Foreach Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181019/17758716)*.

Typically the use of a *stream* is to *aggregate* a set of values, and not necessarily compare and contrast them.
*[Lesson: Aggregate Operations (The Java™ Tutorials > Collections)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

Here is an example utilizing the *[Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html)* class, and the *[Collector#of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...))* method.

Essentially, during the collect, you can retrieve the previous element, from whatever has already been collected.

For the *[BiConsumer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html)* argument, *a* is your collected elements, thus far.

```java
List<RecordB> l
    = listA.stream()
           .collect(
               Collector.<RecordA, List<RecordB>, List<RecordB>>of(
                   ArrayList::new,
                   (a, b) -> {
                       if (a.isEmpty()) a.add(new RecordB(b.id, b.value, 0));
                       else {
                           RecordB x = a.get(a.size() - 1);
                           a.add(new RecordB(b.id, b.value, b.value - x.value));
                       }
                   },
                   (a, b) -> {
                       a.addAll(b);
                       return a;
                   },
                   x -> x));
```

Output

```
1, 10, 0
2, 15, 5
3, 25, 10
4, 30, 5
```

On a final note, you may want to get rid of the *RecordB* class, and just utilize a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)*.

```java
Map<RecordA, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
RecordA a, b;
m.put(a = listA.get(0), 0);
for (int i = 1, n = listA.size(); i < n; i++)
    m.put(b = listA.get(i), -a.value + (a = b).value);
```

Comment: This collector is incorrect. When the workload is split, the accumulator function will treat each chunk’s first element as if it was the entire stream’s first element instead of comparing it with its predecessor (which could only happen in the merge function).

Answer (score 0):

This functionality won't be ready for production use for a while yet, but the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature can be used to achieve the desired result:

```java
RecordA firstA = listA.getFirst();
RecordB firstB =
        new RecordB(firstA.getId(), firstA.getValue(), firstA.getValue());

List<RecordB> listB = Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(firstB),
        listA.stream()
                .gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2))
                .map(w -> new RecordB(w.get(1).getId(), w.get(1).getValue(),
                        w.get(1).getValue() - w.get(0).getValue())))
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int)) gatherer to convert the lists's stream from `Stream<RecordA>` to a pairwise `Stream<List<RecordA>>`.  Each of these two-element lists is then transformed to a `RecordB` using the existing [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method.  The first element is manually constructed and concatenated to the beginning of the stream as it won't be part of the sliding window due to not having a previous element.

```
listA.stream()
    [(1, 10), (2, 15), (3, 25), (4, 30)]

.gather(Gatherer.windowSliding(2))
    [
      [(1, 10), (2, 15)],
      [(2, 15), (3, 25)],
      [(3, 25), (4, 30)]
    ]

.map(w -> new RecordB(...))
    [(2, 15, 5), (3, 25, 10), (4, 30, 5)]]

Stream.concat(firstB, listA.stream().gather(...).map(...))
    [(1, 10, 10), (2, 15, 5), (3, 25, 10), (4, 30, 5)]]
```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a given size, where each subsequent window includes all elements of the previous window except for the least recent, and adds the next element in the stream. […]
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows2 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2)).toList();
>
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows6 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(6)).toList();
> ```